# Xamarin CarouselViewControl support auto slide to next item?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

just wonder to know how to set it up to Xamarin CarouselViewControl? I manage to find it in other product but not in Xamarin?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stock Xamarin.Forms CarouselView does not support this at this time. The team is working on reimplementing the CarouselView from the ground up and "auto slide" is on the list as well.

You can find the full proposal and progress here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4996

Answer (score 5):

You can implement this by attaching **`Behaviour`** to the CarouselViewControl

**XAML:**

```
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
xmlns:behaviour="clr-namespace:TestApp.Behaviours;assembly=TestApp"

<cv:CarouselViewControl x:Name="carousel"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MySampleItems}"
                        ShowIndicators="true"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">

    <cv:CarouselViewControl.Behaviors>
         <behaviour:AutoscrollCarouselBehavior /> 
    </cv:CarouselViewControl.Behaviors>

    <cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemsSource>
       <!--Content of Carousel goes here-->
    </cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemsSource>

</cv:CarouselViewControl>
```

**AutoscrollCarouselBehavior.cs** [Reference](https://gist.github.com/salvador-guerrero/a8332a917af40f944ed8c3feb70eaca3)

```
public class AutoscrollCarouselBehavior : Behavior<CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.CarouselViewControl>
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Scroll delay in milliseconds
     /// </summary>
     public int Delay { get; set; } = 3000;

     private bool runTimer;
     private CarouselViewControl attachedCarousel;

     protected override void OnAttachedTo(CarouselViewControl bindable)
     {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        runTimer = true;
        attachedCarousel = bindable;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Delay), () =>
        {
            MoveCarousel();
            return runTimer;
         });

      }

      protected override void OnDetachingFrom(CarouselViewControl bindable)
      {
          runTimer = false;
          base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
      }

      void MoveCarousel()
      {
         if (attachedCarousel.ItemsSource != null)
         {
             if (attachedCarousel.Position < attachedCarousel.ItemsSource.GetCount() - 1)
              {
                  attachedCarousel.Position++;
              }
              else
              {
                  attachedCarousel.Position = 0;
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

This will auto scroll the carousel page, you can set the `Delay` as per the requirement.